# Repository not found, but I can't add it either

Tags: git, github

After changing to 2 factory authentication, I get the following error when I try to pull/push to/from a remote branch such as

```
git pull origin master
```

:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/my-organization/my-project.git/' not found
```

However, when I try to add the repository

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my-organization/my-project.git
```

I get an error

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

I follow [this document](https://gist.github.com/wikimatze/9790374) to resolve invalid username or password error.

Now, How can I resolve this repository error?

Update:

I try to start out on the repository with

```
git clone https://github.com/my-organization/my-project.git
```

And I get the same error:

```
Cloning into 'my-project'...
git: 'credential-netrc' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. <-- don't know how this comes up
Username for 'https://github.com': my-username
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/my-organization/my-project.git/' not found
```

Comment: Please give an example command that gives the error. It looks like you have an erroneous trailing slash on the URL.

Comment: Did you put this url **https://github.com/<organization>/<project>.git**, or you changed it with your own informations?

Comment: How to get rid of the trailing slash?

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that it has a remote URL, but it cannot find a repository there. When you try to add another one, Git correctly tells you that you already have a remote for origin.

To change the URL, use `git remote set-url origin <url>`. You probably need to remove that trailing slash, but to be sure copy the URL directly from Github's "Clone or Download" button.

If you're [using 2-factor auth](https://blog.github.com/2013-09-03-two-factor-authentication/) with `https` URLs, you need to use your [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) instead of your password. Or save a lot of headaches and [use ssh](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).

Comment: After running  "git remote set-url origin https://github.com/my-organization/my-project.git", I get "git pull origin master" and get the same error. - repository ... not found. There is a backward slash at the end. Is the source of the problem?

Comment: I do use a PAT generated on the github site. Otherwise, I won't be able to go this far.

Comment: @vic It's just a normal https URL. There should be no backslashes. For example, `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i.git`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought. I try to find a way to remove the last backward slash.